CSS не связывается с HTML
Не понимаю почему они никак не связываются друг с другом
Вот мой html/css


.first #name {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

div {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

#span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4em;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

#second {
  text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Gefestia</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first">
    <div id="name">GEFESTIA</div>
    <div id="phone">Контактный номер: +7(916)303-33-92</div>
    <div id="rem">РЕМОНТ КВАРТИР ПОД КЛЮЧ</div>
    <div id="mosc">В МОСКВЕ И МОСКОВСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ</div>
    <div id="fast">Быстро | Качественно | В срок</div>
    <a href="#link"><span>Рассчитать стоимость</span></a>
  </div>
  <!--div id="link">Рассчитать стоимость ремонта квартиры у нас</div> это в самый низ страницы-->
  <div id="second">
    <div>Мы Gefestia - ремонтно-подрядная организация, готовая на себя взять ответственность за создание уюта в вашем доме.</div>
    <div>За 10 лет работы мы сдали 500 квартир и 25 ремонтируются в настоящее время. Посмотрите как мы это делаем!</div>
  </div>




Логичный вопрос — откуда эта связь должна взяться?

Руководство для новых пользователей Stack Overflow на русском — пункт 2

Наверное надо css подключить к html?

 примерно такую штуку нужно подключить в head

Вам нужно подключить css к файлу:

Вместо css/main-style.css - ваш путь к файлу

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Gefestia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first">
            <div id="name">GEFESTIA</div>
            <div id="phone">Контактный номер: +7(916)303-33-92</div>
            <div id="rem">РЕМОНТ КВАРТИР ПОД КЛЮЧ</div>
            <div id="mosc">В МОСКВЕ И МОСКОВСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ</div>
            <div id="fast">Быстро | Качественно | В срок</div>  
            <a href="#link"><span>Рассчитать стоимость</span></a>
        </div>
        <!--div id="link">Рассчитать стоимость ремонта квартиры у нас</div> это в самый низ страницы-->
        <div id="second">
            <div>Мы Gefestia - ремонтно-подрядная организация, готовая на себя взять ответственность за создание уюта в вашем доме.</div>
            <div>За 10 лет работы мы сдали 500 квартир и 25 ремонтируются в настоящее время. Посмотрите как мы это делаем!</div>
            </div>


спасибо!!!!!!!!

вы забыли подключить css
< link rel="stylesheet" href="путь к css" />

